# How to block a thread for some time until it executes the return statement, on Android

Tags: android, observable, threadpool, rx-java2

I am making multiple network requests under a for loop. And I want the return statement after the for loop to be executed after all the network calls are completed.

I have tried `Obsever.fromIterable` in Java and in the `doOnNext` I updated the value to be returned, but the issue is I wasn't able to return value from `doOnNext`. I have to return `mediadetails` object from this code

```
// Add some value to the JSON object (mediaDetails) using network calls
try {
    // Gets an array list
    Observable.fromIterable((ArrayList<LinkedTreeMap>) statements.get("P180"))
        .map(item -> {
            //extract id from the item 
            getLabelForDepiction(id).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new Consumer<JsonObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(JsonObject jsonObject) throws Exception {
                            jsonArray.add(jsonObject);
                        }
                    });
            return jsonArray;
        })
        .doOnNext(subscriber -> {
            // Again update media details object
            mediaDetails.add("Depiction", (JsonArray) subscriber);
        })
} catch (Exception e) {
   // Handle exception
}
```

I want to return the media details object after the catch statement but it gets executed even before all the network calls are finished

Comment: Have you tried `.blockingGet()`?

Comment: No what does this function do?

Comment: Blocks until the observable is done emitting (onComplete).

Comment: Although you shouldn't even have a `jsonArray` outside of the `Observable`'s scope itself.

Comment: `Although you shouldn't even have a jsonArray outside of the Observable's scope itself.  `-----Why?

Comment: Because that should be done with `.toList().map(`

Answer (score 0):

`getLabelForDepiction(id).subscribeOn` is executed asynchronously and calls `accept` when its done. Nevertheless you return `jsonArray` which can be empty before the asynchronous statement is completed.

You can simply add a method call inside `accept` callback to make use of the jsonObject when its ready, instead of returning a value.

```
.subscribe(new Consumer<JsonObject>() {
         @Override
         public void accept(JsonObject jsonObject) throws Exception {
           //jsonArray.add(jsonObject);
              useJsonObject(jsonObject); 
            }
           });

public void useJsonObject(JsonObject jsonObject){
   ...
   jsonArray.add(jsonObject);
   //then make use of jsonArray here
   ...
}
```

Comment: hey i want to add this to `mediaDetails` object then return `mediaDetails` at the end of this code

Comment: Add to your question the block expecting the return value.

Comment: Thanks I have added

Comment: I can;t see any changes in your post... Your current post is a method block that returns `jsonArray`. So add to your post the statement line or code block that is expecting the returned `jsonArray` or calling the method block. I believe it should be something like **Array<Obj> blahblah = getJsonArray();** where **getJsonArray()** is the code you posted in your current question